# on selecting a radio button in a table row the color of row should be changed

Tags: javascript, html, struts

I am developing an employee registration module using struts 1.3.8 and hibernate. 
I need to show a table that is generated dynamically to display all the registration requests.

My requirement is...

> In each row with all details of a particular employee 2 radio buttons
>   are there for approval *n* reject.  If row is clicked (any where except
>   radio buttons) color of entire row should be pink. If *reject* radio
>   button is clicked the color of entire row should change to red and on
>   clicking *approve* radio button row color should be green.

Comment: atleast show me some codes so that i can figure out what you done tomake it

Comment: Shailesh, welcome to StackOverflow. Here as SO we do not do things for you. Instead, we help you out when you're stuck. Try to solve this problem yourself, get stuck, then show us what you tried and we'd love to get you unstuck.

Comment: Dear Ayman Safadi,

Actually I am a newbie in development. But now I got some basic idea and I solved this problem.
Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign a row id to each row like this

```
<tr id="row1"><td>YOUR CONTENT HERE</td></tr>
```

on radiobutton select event , call the below function as `changeColor(this.id)`

```
function changeColor(id)
{
//and now on the click of approve button, do this is javascript function:

    document.getElementById(id).setAttribute("style","background-color:green");

//and similarly, on reject:

    document.getElementById(id).setAttribute("style","background-color:red");
}
```

I hope you get the idea...

Comment: why use java script when struts has iterator

Comment: i don't think there is a need for any server side scripting for a client side job.. And if struts converts this to a client side code at the end, then why to use it. I mean it's not that hard to do it directly

Comment: Dear nsthethunderbolt,

Thank you for reply. Really I got the idea and now it is working fine.